# Uninitialized constant error when running ruby specs on linux, not on windows

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, rspec

I have a series of selenium/capybara specs that I'm running via rspec in a ruby project. Thus far I have been running them exclusively on a windows machine without issue. Now I am trying to migrate to a Linux machine and I'm running into issues all over the place.

In my `spec_helper.rb` which every one of my test files requires, I start off with this bit below. Yet when I run my tests on the Linux server, I'm getting a dozens of uninitialized constant errors. Basically the first class the code hits is being declared uninitialized despite having been initialized elsewhere.

```
# frozen-string-literal: true

require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'site_prism'

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/helpers/*.rb'].each do |helper|
  require helper
end

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/page_objects/mixins/*.rb'].each do |page_object|
  require page_object
end
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/page_objects/sections/*.rb'].each do |page_object|
  require page_object
end

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/page_objects/*/*.rb'].each do |page_object|
  require page_object
end
```

one such stacktrace:

An error occurred while loading ./demo_spec.rb.

```
Failure/Error: iframe :export_modal, Pages::ExportModal, :xpath, '//*[@id="qPopupWindow"]/iframe'

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Pages::ExportModal
# /dr01/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/DEVSYS-RSM2FT-JOB1/spec/page_objects/pages/entity_gl_periods.rb:18:in `<class:EntityGlPeriods>'
# /dr01/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/DEVSYS-RSM2FT-JOB1/spec/page_objects/pages/entity_gl_periods.rb:2:in `<module:Pages>'
# /dr01/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/DEVSYS-RSM2FT-JOB1/spec/page_objects/pages/entity_gl_periods.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# /dr01/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/DEVSYS-RSM2FT-JOB1/spec/spec_helper.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
# /dr01/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/DEVSYS-RSM2FT-JOB1/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `each'
# /dr01/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/DEVSYS-RSM2FT-JOB1/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
# ./demo_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

Comment: please post stack trace errors or we are shooting in the dark

Answer (score 0):

Stack trace tells you error is on line 21 of `spec_helper`

The error somewhere in here:

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/page_objects/*/*.rb'].each do |page_object|
  require page_object
end
```

If you're able to get into the server console, see what this actually returns and compare to your windows environment.

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/page_objects/*/*.rb']
```

It seems like the load order of your requires are not firing correctly.  Is it possible there are permission errors on the directories you're trying to read/load from?

Comment: so I do get the same errors when I try to load the files in the irb console on the server. It really makes no sense given that it works fine on the PC. As for the permissions, they are the same on both systems. 644.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`? Are you using bundler? If so also try prepend `bundle exec rspec`

Comment: Sorry I thought I posted this comment yesterday. I did both and verified that I'm using the same versions of all gems on both machines.